# Recortar um pedaço da imagem usando mouse

Tags: delphi

Olá, tenho a seguinte situação, em um FORM tenho uma imagem qualquer, preciso selecionar uma parte da imagem através do clique do MOUSE, e assim que eu soltar o botão do mouse, essa parte que selecionei seja SALVA!

Eu achei uma questão parecida com a minha, mas não consegui adapta-la para usar em imagem, apenas no FORM, segue o link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32427396/create-a-rectangle-hole-on-form-with-my-mouse

No caso desse tópico acima, ele usa o mouse para efetuar um "furo" no FORM, o que eu preciso é recortar e salvar um pedaço da imagem.

Agradeço qualquer ajuda!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Segue exemplo de como fazer.

Adicione um componente `TImage`, defina uma imagem na propriedade `Picture`, claro, você pode usar um sistema de carregamento para a imagem como preferir, no caso do exemplo vamos iniciar o componente já com uma imagem definida!

Declaração de Variáveis Globais (prefiro sempre fazer assim):

```
num,
StartX,
StartY,
OldStartX,
OldStartY,
OldEndX,
OldEndY : Integer;
IsDown : Boolean;
JPG: TJpegImage;
Bmp,
Bmp1,
Bmp2 : TBitmap;
```

No evento `MouseDown` do componente `TImage` vamos pegar as coordenadas X e Y do Mouse:

```
procedure TForm5.Image1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  IsDown := True;
  StartX := X;
  StartY := Y;
  OldStartX := X;
  OldStartY := Y;
  OldEndX := X;
  OldEndY := Y;
end;
```

Agora no evento `MouseMove` do componente `TImage` vamos desenhar a área de seleção:

```
procedure TForm5.Image1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if IsDown then
  begin
    Canvas.Pen.Style := psDot;
    Canvas.Pen.Mode := pmNotXor;
    Canvas.Rectangle(OldStartX, OldStartY, OldEndX, OldEndY);
    OldEndX := X;
    OldEndY := Y;
    Canvas.Rectangle(StartX, StartY, X, Y);
  end;
end;
```

Pronto, chegamos na parte final, vamos soltar o botão do Mouse e salvar a imagem.

No evento `MouseUp` do componente `TImage`:

```
procedure TForm5.Image1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  IsDown := False;
  Canvas.Pen.Style := psDot;
  Canvas.Pen.Mode  := pmNotXor;
  Canvas.Rectangle(OldStartX, OldStartY, OldEndX, OldEndY);

  Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
  JPG := TJpegImage.Create;
  JPG.Assign(Bmp);
  num := 90;

  Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('D:\imagem_original.bmp');
  image1.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;

  if not (Image1.Picture.Graphic is TBitmap) then
    raise Exception.Create('A imagem não é um Bitmap');

  Bmp2 := TBitmap(Image1.Picture.Graphic);

  Bmp1 := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    Bmp1.Width := Abs(OldEndX - OldStartX);
    Bmp1.Height := Abs(OldEndY - OldStartY);

    Bmp1.Canvas.CopyRect(Rect(0, 0, Bmp1.Width, Bmp1.Height), Bmp2.Canvas, Rect(OldStartX, OldStartY, OldEndX, OldEndY));
    Bmp1.SaveToFile('D:\imagem_recortada.bmp');
  finally
    Bmp1.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Observe que nessa linha estou salvando a imagem Automaticamente ao soltar o botão do Mouse, você pode personalizar isto facilmente, faça o teste:

1 - Comente a linha que contem, `Bmp1.SaveToFile('D:\imagem_recortada.bmp');`

2 - Remova da seção `finally` o `Bmp1.Free;`

3 - Adicione no evento Click de um componente TButton:

```
procedure TForm5.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Bmp1.SaveToFile('D:\imagem_recortada.bmp');
  Bmp1.Free;
end;
```

E claro, você pode usar um `SavePictureDialog` para ficar mais profissional!

Prontinho!

Comment: Júnior Moreira, perfeito cara, deu certo, eu só tive que tirar essa linha que estava dando pau: Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('e:\imagem_original.bmp');, no caso do seu exemplo eu só posso usar imagem .bmp, se eu quiser .jpg dentro do IMAGE1, o que eu preciso mudar ?

Comment: Pode sim, e para usar JPEG você não deve usar essa linha 'if not (Image1.Picture.Graphic is TBitmap) then' e nas uses lá em cima Declare JPEG.

Comment: Júnior Moreira, essas opções eu preciso mudar também  Bmp1 := TBitmap.Create; ? no caso para usar JPG ?

Answer (score 2):

Para JPEG é necessário conversão, para não ficar uma resposta muito extensa resolvi postar uma nova Resposta!

Bem semelhante o método anterior,

Declare as seguintes variáveis globais:

```
PosicaoX,
PosicaoY : Integer;
Bmp1, Bmp2: TBitmap;
Jpg: TJPEGImage;
```

Crie uma `Procedure` com esse bloco de código:

```
procedure TfrmPrincipal.CopyJPGArea(JPimag: TJPEGImage; Top, Left, Width, Height: Integer; NewImage: TImage);
begin
  //Primeiro convertemos a JPEG em BMP
  JPimag.DIBNeeded;
  Bmp1 := TBitmap.Create;
  Bmp1.Assign(JPimag);
  //Copiamos a parte que queremos
  Bmp2 := TBitmap.Create;
  Bmp2.Width := Width;
  Bmp2.Height := Height;
  Bmp2.Canvas.CopyRect(Rect(0, 0, Width, Height), Bmp1.Canvas, Rect(Top, Left, Top + Width, Left + Height));
  //Transferindo a parte copiada para um TImage na memória
  NewImage.Picture.assign(Bmp2);
  //Liberando as temporarias
  Bmp2.free;
  Bmp1.free;
end;
```

Adicione um componente TButton, atribua o nome `btnAbrir` e no seu evento Click:

```
procedure TfrmPrincipal.btnAbrirClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (OpenPictureDialog1.Execute) then
  begin
    Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile(OpenPictureDialog1.FileName);
  end;
end;
```

Adicione 2 componentes `TImage`, nos eventos `MouseDown` e MouseUp do Image1:

```
procedure TfrmPrincipal.Image1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  PosicaoX := X;
  PosicaoY := Y;
end;

procedure TfrmPrincipal.Image1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  Jpg := TJPEGImage.Create;
  Jpg.Assign(Image1.Picture);
  CopyJPGArea(Jpg, PosicaoX, PosicaoY, X - PosicaoX, Y - PosicaoY, Image2);
  Jpg.Free;
end;
```

Este é o procedimento para copiar uma parte do JPEG do Image1 para o Image2, agora use minha outra resposta e você já poderá salvar a imagem, com imaginação você pode mesclar os dois Códigos em 1 e conseguira ler ambos formatos!

Observe que eu não adicionei os métodos de criação do Retângulo de seleção! Você já os tem na primeira resposta! Assim fica melhor o estudo, mãos a obra!